# Codeigniter base_url not working when deleting, adding and updating the data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making a codeigniter program that can Add, Edit, Delete, Update and View the data in the database. The logical error here is that the base_url is not working at all. When I click the delete, add and update button it goes to the `about:blank` page.

```
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1" width="50%">
            <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th>
                <th>phone</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

            <?php

                $i=1;
                foreach($query as $row)
                {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'/index.php/emp/update/'.$row->id; ?>">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="<?php echo base_url().'/index.php/emp/delete/'.$row->id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                    $i++;
                }
                ?>

                <tr><td colspan="7"><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/emp/add_new">Add New</a></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: what is exact error?

Comment: I cannot add, delete and update the data.

Comment: Did you try to check with `inspect element` in your browser?

Comment: yes and this is the result: `<a href="http://::1/codeigniter//index.php/emp/update/11">Edit</a>` and I am wondering why it goes to the `about:blank` page.

Comment: Did you define `base_url` in your `config.php` file?

Comment: try removing `leading slash ("/")` from `index.php`

Comment: what is your application/config.php

Comment: I didn't define the base_url

Comment: After I defined the base_url in the config.php the result is this:  `http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/emp/localhost//index.php/emp/update/11` it has a double localhosts

Comment: is it ok to change it like this: `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';` it seems to work fine after I change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to used `base_url`. First step, You must have to `URL helper` loaded in your `application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

Or you can load `URL Helper` Manually by

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Then You can call `base_url` like

```
echo base_url();
```

But Remember One thing,

> If this `base_url` is not set in your `config.php` file then CodeIgniter will get the protocol,
>   domain and path to your installation.

But If you are define `base_url` in your `application/config/config.php` then `base_url` is loaded from here.

Comment: where will I load the url helper `$this->load->helper('url');`?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the uri to the base_url() function as a parameter.

```
<td><a href="<?php echo base_url('/index.php/emp/update/'.$row->id);   ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: still goes to the `about:blank` page

Answer (score 0):

Change the base_url in `config.php` depending on your link or folder

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue try by using in-built functions provided by Codeigniter

Follow steps as below,

Step 1: Firstly, you have to define base_url in config.php file as below,

```
$host = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host = $host.str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $host;
```

Step 2: Instead of using `<a>` tag use `anchor()` method provided by URL helper.

For this you need load URL helper as follows,
$this->load->helper('url');

Replace your code with the following code,

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="1" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Address</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $i=1;
    foreach($query as $row)
    { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->phone; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php echo anchor('emp/update/'.$row->id, 'Edit')?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo anchor('emp/delete/'.$row->id, 'Delete')?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
            $i++;
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">
            <?php echo anchor('emp/add_new', 'Add New')?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This will resolve your issue.